# How to find IP address lease info using WPA2 Enterprise

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm trying to find the DHCP lease info for my wifi connection on a network using WPA2 Enterprise and PEAP. I can do this in Windows using `ipconfig /all` which shows both when the lease was issued and when the lease expires.

Looking in `/var/lib/dhcp` I cannot find any recent entries. All of them appear to be for other wifi networks. Also my `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` file is empty. So I'm wondering if the information is kept somewhere else in the case of PEAP connections, but have been unable to find any info about this after a few google searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in /var/lib/NetworkManager for the lease.

---

I do see an old lease in my /var/lib/dhcp dating back to April, when I think I updated my system from 12.04 to 14.04.  I have no idea why such a change was made.

Comment: Do you know why some leases end up in `/var/lib/dhcp` and some in `/var/lib/NetworkManager`? Was my assumption correct that PEAP leases end up in the path you provided? I've never made a connection using anything other than the Network Manager GUI so it just seems a little weird to me.